# Waking up a specific thread from sleep from another thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep, wait

I've been chasing my tail on this one for days now, and I'm going crazy. I'm a total amateur and totally new to python, so please excuse my stupidity.

My main thread repeatedly checks a database for an entry and then starts threads for every new entry that it finds in the database.

The threads that it starts up basically poll the database for a value and if it doesn't find that value, it does some things and then it sleeps for 60 seconds and starts over.

Simplified non-code for the started up thread

```
while True:
    stop = _Get_a_Value_From_Database_for_Exit() #..... a call to DBMS 
    If stop = 0:
        Do_stuff()
        time.sleep(60)
    else:
        break
```

There could be many of these threads running at any given time. What I'd like to do is have the main thread check another spot in the database for specific value and then can interrupt the sleep in the example above in a specific thread that was started. The goal would be to exit a specific thread like the one listed above without having to wait the remainder of the sleep duration. All of these threads can be referenced by the database id that is shared. I've seen references to **`event.wait()`** and **`event.set()`** been trying to figure out how I replace the **`time.sleep()`** with it, but I have no idea how I could use it to wake up a specific thread instead of all of them.

This is where my ignorance show through: is there a way where I could do something based on database `id` for the event.wait (Like `12345.wait(60)` in the started up thread and `12345.set()`  in the main thread (all dynamic based on the ever changing database **`id`**).

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project is a little complex, and here's my version of it.

- scan database file `/tmp/db.dat`, prefilled with two words
- manager: create a thread for each word; default is a "whiskey" thread and a "syrup" thread
- if a word ends in `_stop`, like `syrup_stop`, tell that thread to die by setting its stop event
- each thread scans the database file and exits if it sees the word `stop`.  It'll also exit if its stop event is set.
- note that if the Manager thread sets a worker's stop_event, the worker will immediately exit. Each thread does a little bit of stuff, but spends most of its time in the `stop_ev.wait()` call. Thus, when the event does get set, it doesn't have to sit around, it can exit immediately.

The server is fun to play around with!  Start it, then send commands to it by adding lines to the database. Try each one of the following:

```
$ echo pie >> /tmp/db.dat  # start new thread

$ echo pie_stop >> /tmp/db.dat # stop thread by event

$ echo whiskey_stop >> /tmp/db.dat # stop another thread "

$ echo stop >> /tmp/db.dat # stop all threads
```

### source

```
import logging, sys, threading, time

STOP_VALUE = 'stop'

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)-4s %(threadName)s %(levelname)s %(message)s", 
    datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
    stream=sys.stderr,
)


class Database(list):
    PATH = '/tmp/db.dat'
    def __init__(self):
        super(Database,self).__init__()
        self._update_lock = threading.Lock()

    def update(self):
        with self._update_lock:
            self[:] = [ line.strip() for line in open(self.PATH) ]

db = Database()

def spawn(events, key):
    events[key] = threading.Event()
    th = threading.Thread(
        target=search_worker,
        kwargs=dict(stop_ev=events[key]),
        name='thread-{}'.format(key),
    )
    th.daemon = True
    th.start()

def search_worker(stop_ev):
    """
    scan database until "stop" found, or our event is set
    """
    logging.info('start')
    while True:
        logging.debug('scan')
        db.update()
        if STOP_VALUE in db:
            logging.info('stopvalue: done')
            return
        if stop_ev.wait(timeout=10):
            logging.info('event: done')
            return 

def manager():
    """
    scan database
    - word: spawn thread if none already
    - word_stop: tell thread to die by setting its stop event
    """
    logging.info('start')
    events = dict()
    while True:
        db.update()
        for key in db:
            if key == STOP_VALUE:
                continue
            if key in events:
                continue
            if key.endswith('_stop'):
                key = key.split('_')[0]
                if key not in events:
                    logging.error('stop: missing key=%s!', key)
                else:
                    # signal thread to stop
                    logging.info('stop: key=%s', key)
                    events[key].set()
                    del events[key]
            else:
                spawn(events, key)
                logging.info('spawn: key=%s', key)
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__=='__main__':

    with open(Database.PATH, 'w') as dbf:
        dbf.write(
        'whiskey\nsyrup\n'
        )

    db.update()
    logging.info('start: db=%s -- %s', db.PATH, db)

    manager_t = threading.Thread(
        target=manager,
        name='manager',
    )
    manager_t.start()
    manager_t.join()
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks for the fantastic, thorough answer! I think this is exactly the direction I needed. I can't wait to attempt to implement it.

Comment: @tonyk4316 let me know how it goes!  it's an interesting project

Comment: This did the trick. Everything I was reading was pointing toward dictionaries, but there were no practical examples on how to implement them in this context. Thanks so much for the help (and the super cool example)!

Comment: I'm so glad it worked out for you -- enjoy! And, everyone loves pie and whiskey ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rather change your design architecture and go in for a distributed process-to-process message-passing, than to repetitively re-chase a dbEngine in an infinite loop with repetitive dbSeek-s for a dumb value, re-test it for an in-equality and then trying to "kill-a-sleep".

Both **`ZeroMQ`** or **`nanomsg`** are smart, broker-less, messaging layers very good in this sense.

A desire to cross-breed fire and water IMHO does not bring anything good for a real-world system.

A smart, scaleable, distributed process-to-process design does.

[image: ( Fig. on a simple distributed process-to-process messaging, courtesy imatix/ZeroMQ )]

( Fig. on a simple distributed process-to-process messaging/coordination, courtesy imatix/ZeroMQ )

Comment: I feel like the character in that meme: "Mmmm. Yeah. I know some of these words." I understand that what I'm doing isn't efficient, but I'm just developing something simple for my own personal home use. Attempting to wrap my head around this is outside the scope of this project. I appreciate the input though!